# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException when I type a decimal number

Tags: java, syntax-error, typeerror

I do not understand what is wrong here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner cl = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a = cl.nextDouble();
        System.out.print(a);

    }
}
```

I get this error whenever I type x.x:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Comment: You can not supply alpha characters (like `x`) to the **Scanner#nextDouble()** method other than `+`, `-` and or course `.`. Numerical Digits only. You need to make sure there is no whitespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

Scanners default to the system locale. Your system locale is set to Dutch, or some other locale that uses commas as decimal separator. You have 2 options:

1. Type `5,5` instead.
2. Immediately after making a `new Scanner`, configure it to your liking. THat involves calling `cl.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);`, and probably also `cl.useDelimiter("\\R")` (which means: The user is expected to hit enter after every input. Versus the mostly useless 'any amount of whitespace' default delimiter).

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you also know where I can change system locale?

Comment: In your windows, linux, or mac system settings.